# Make primary voting process more explicit

Tags: feature-request, election, moderator-primaries

Should the number of votes that a user is eligible to cast be listed somewhere on the primary voting page? I found that I could cast one up or down per candidate.. but I had to look around for the answer.

Comment: To further elaborate before I looked it up I was under the false assumption that I had 3 votes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the right sidebar of the primary page:

> There is no commenting in this phase, only one up or down vote per candidate. The candidate vote scores are all public. Initial voting should provide a rough sense of which candidates are most electable.

Maybe it's not the most obvious thing in the world, but I think the  **"one up or down vote per candidate"** gets the point across.

Comment: Personally I think it would be more noticable in (under) the "Voting Closes In n Days" banner above the voting section.